# Variable does not exist in Trigger

Tags: trigger

I have a problem with my code. This is a Trigger on Opportunity. When the Opportunity is closed and won, we create a new Policy__c from that opportunity. The Policy__c also has a related list, called PolicyERN__c. This is the part I am having trouble with. 
The line on which it says:

`Map<Id, Policy__c> polsWithJunc = new Map<Id, Policy__c>(
                [Select Id, (Select ERN__c, Policy__c From PolicyERNs__r) 
                 From Policy__c 
                 WHERE Id IN :polIds]);`

, the `polIDs` is not defined. I am not sure how to get these polIDs. They should be the IDs of `newpolicies`. It would be great if someone could help me amend my code. Tia.

```
 trigger CreatePolicy on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    //Mcreate a filtered map of opps excluding any Targets
    Map<Id, Opportunity> mapRealOpps = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity anOpp: Trigger.new){
        if(!anOpp.Target__c){
            mapRealOpps.put(anOpp.Id, anOpp);
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.IsUpdate && Trigger.IsAfter){
        CurrencyChange.cascade(Trigger.newMap,Trigger.oldMap);        
    }
    if (TriggerStopper.StopOpp) {    
    } else if (Renewal_Settings.Instance.Triggers_Enabled) {

        TriggerStopper.StopOpp = true;

        List<Policy__c> newPolicies = new List<Policy__c>();
        List<Opportunity> renewalOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
        Set<id> accountIds = new Set<id>();
        for (Opportunity o : mapRealOpps.values()) {
            Opportunity oldOpp;
            if (trigger.isUpdate) {
                oldOpp = trigger.oldMap.get(o.id);
            }
            if ((trigger.isInsert && o.isClosed && o.isWon) || (oldOpp != null && o.isClosed && o.isWon && !oldOpp.isWon)) {

                Policy__c newPolicy = new Policy__c(
                    Client_Name__c = o.AccountId, 
                    Source_Opportunity__c = o.id,
                    Start_Date__c = o.Policy_Inception_Date__c,
                    End_Date__c = o.Expiry_Date__c,
                    //Add policy number from opp if available
                    Policy_Number__c = o.Policy_Number__c
                    );

                newPolicies.add(newPolicy);
            }
            accountIds.add(o.AccountId);
        }

        INSERT newPolicies;

        Map<Id, Policy__c> polsWithJunc = new Map<Id, Policy__c>([Select Id, (Select ERN__c, Policy__c From PolicyERNs__r) From Policy__c 
                                WHERE Id IN :polIds]);

        Map<Id, Policy__c> newPolsByOppId = new Map<Id, Policy__c>();
        for (Policy__c pol : newPolicies) {
            newPolsByOppId.put(pol.Opporunity, pol);
        }


        List<PolicyERN__c> newPolERNs = new List<PolicyERN__c>();

        for (Opportunity opp : scopedOpps) {
            Policy__c pol = polsWithJunc.get(opp.Policy__c);

        for (PolicyERN__c polERN : pol.PolicyERN__c) { 
            PolicyERN__c newPolERN = polERN.clone();
            newPolERN.Policy__c = newPolsByOppId.get(opp.Id).Id;
            newPolERNs.add(newPolERN);
            }
        }

        insert newPolERNs;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the following in your SOQL and it should work.

> Map polsWithJunc = new Map([Select Id,
>   (Select ERN__c, Policy__c From PolicyERNs__r) From Policy__c 
>                           WHERE Id IN :newPolicies ]);

Answer (score 0):

Once you have inserted the `newPolicies` list the record id's will be added to that list.

So in order to create a set of id's from that list (which you will need for the query), you can do this:

```
INSERT newPolicies;
// define the id set
Set<Id> polIds = new Set<Id>();
// add the policy ids to the set
for(Policy__c thePolicy : newPolicies){
   polIds.add(thePolicy.Id);
}

Map<Id, Policy__c> polsWithJunc = new Map<Id, Policy__c>([Select Id, (Select ERN__c, Policy__c From PolicyERNs__r) From Policy__c 
                        WHERE Id IN :polIds]);
```

Comment: Can't we just used `newPolicies` instead of `polIds` in the `WHERE` clause of SOQL?

Comment: @MahmoodButt that should be possible as well indeed and much more efficient. Worth posting an answer I'd say!